# Proxied nodejs site not loading over HTTPS in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, https, proxypass

I have a node server running on a port and I am using Apache to proxy pass to it. I have setup SSL on the virtual host and HTTP works fine but HTTPS times out and says `Connection Refused`

Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@test.co
        ServerName dl.test.co
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8004/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8004/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@test.co
        ServerName dl.test.co
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8004/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8004/

        SSLEngine on
        SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/sub.class1.server.ca.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had not proxied 443 through our firewall. Doh!

Comment: can you set your answer as valid ? thanks